# Q-matrix vs. P-matrix description of a Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a continuous time Markov chain $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ on some state space $S$ with transition matrix (P-matrix) $p_t(x,y)$, the probability density of jumping from $x$ to $y$ in time $t$.

The associated Q-matrix is defined as

$$q(x,y) = \frac{d}{d t}p_t(x,y)\vert_{t=0}$$

and offers an *infinitesimal* description of the chain.

What are advantages and disadvantages of investigating the Markov with either the Q- or the P-matrix?

Are the two descriptions any different in the case of $S$ being finite or do the methods only differ for $S$ being countably infinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two equivalent descriptions of the same semi-group. You mentioned how to deduce $q$ from $(p_t)$, note that, conversely, $p_t=\mathrm e^{tq}$ for every $t\geqslant0$.

Comment: Do there have to be assumptions on $Q$ for the exponential series to converge? (which would imply that there is no one-to-one correspondence) Is one description favorable over the other from a practical point of view when working with Markov chains?

Comment: The exponential series always converges, for the same reason that in the scalar case, plus the submultiplicativity of the norm. "More or less favorable": this all depends on what one wants to do with these.

Comment: What happens if the transition rates are time-dependent, say like Weibull hazard rates?  Is it still possible to get an expression for the evolution o f the probability matrix $P(t)$